# Failed to load module

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

It's my first day actually experimenting with AngularJS and I'm hitting an error.

> Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

[Error Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=PP&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.23%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DPP%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fdrkameleon%2FDocuments%2FPeppermint%2FPeppermint%2Fhtml%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:6:450%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fdrkameleon%2FDocuments%2FPeppermint%2FPeppermint%2Fhtml%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:20:494%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fdrkameleon%2FDocuments%2FPeppermint%2FPeppermint%2Fhtml%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:21:502%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fdrkameleon%2FDocuments%2FPeppermint%2FPeppermint%2Fhtml%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:33:267%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fdrkameleon%2FDocuments%2FPeppermint%2FPeppermint%2Fhtml%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:7:290)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fdrkameleon%2FDocuments%2FPeppermint%2FPeppermint%2Fhtml%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:33:207)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20gc%20(file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fdrkameleon%2FDocuments%2FPeppermint%2FPeppermint%2Fhtml%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:36:309)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fdrkameleon%2FDocuments%2FPeppermint%2FPeppermint%2Fhtml%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:18:170)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fc%20(file:%2F%2F%2FUsers%2Fdrkameleon%2FDocuments%2FPeppermint%2FPeppermint%2Fhtml%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:18:387)

---

**The AngularJS code :**

```
var PP = angular.module('PP', []);

PP.controller('documentController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.documents = [
        {
            'filename': 'Untitled-1',
            'content': 'Content-1'
        },
        {
            'filename': 'Untitled-2',
            'content': 'Content-2'
        },
        {
            'filename': 'Untitled-3',
            'content': 'Content-3'
        },
    ];
});
```

**And the HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="PP">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap Core Template</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/jquery.layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="custom/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- IE Support -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Main Wrapper -->
        <div class="container-fluid ui-layout-center" id="wrapper" ng-controller="documentController">

            <!-- Editor Tabs -->  
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="tabbar">
                    <li ng-repeat="document in documents">
                        <a href="#{{document.filename}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            <button class="close closeTab" type="button">x</button>
                            {{document.filename}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- Editor Contents -->
            <div class="row-fluid content"> 
                <div class="tab-content" style="height:100%;">
                    <div ng-repeat="document in documents">
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="{{document.filename}}">{{document.content}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Panel Tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs panel-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li id="console-trigger"><a href="#console-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></i></a></li>
                <li id="search-trigger"><a href="#search-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <!-- Panel Contents -->
        <div class="ui-layout-south">
            <div class="tab-content" id="panel-content">

                <!-- Console -->
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="console-tab">

                </div>

                <!-- Search -->
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="search-tab">

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.layout.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.tabdrop.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/mustache.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="extras/ace/ace.js"></script>
        <script src="custom/script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Looks right, lets see the HTML. Probably missing an `ng-app` from somewhere.

Comment: @tymeJV Just updated it! :-)

Comment: Can you post your script.js? I'm assuming that is app.js renamed.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall Christopher, `script.js` contains just a few jquery setups and the AngularJS code above. Nothing extraordinary.

Comment: Super weird. I can reproduce the issue in a fiddle, but I don't know why it's not picking up on the PP module variable. http://jsfiddle.net/xk5nv3rj/

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall Well, I suppose I am super-unlucky then, having to face a super weird issue at my first try... :S

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon I have it working in a Plunkr, but I have no idea the difference. Just copied/pasted in. http://plnkr.co/edit/uW3nhDjHJSqSKmmIboth?p=info

Comment: if using jsfiddle, choose no -wrap from the left panel

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon can you confirm that all JS files are being loaded?

Comment: @bmleite Great point, buddy. That was it! `angular.min.js.map` not being read... :-)